# Error: SPFx loader is not present in the page in SharePoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, trial-version

[image: Screenshot: SPFx loader is not present in the page]I am getting this error all of sudden in my SharePoint 365 trial site.I didn't perform any major changes.i have just removed 3 default web parts from my home page and it has started showing me this error.

> SPFx loader is not present in the page in SharePoint 365.

I am not getting any root cause.
Can anybody help me to get out this?

I'm getting the same error.  I'm able to access older sharepoint site, but not the "new"  office 365 version.

Comment: tag your question with the spfx tags so the Microsofties notice it

Comment: I got same error. Please let me know if anyone have solution for this error?